# $block->getLoadedProductCollection() is breaking pagination - Magneto EE 1.14.2.2

Tags: javascript, php, magento, zend-framework

So our custom data layer for Magento: https://github.com/QubitProducts/UniversalVariable-Magento-Extension works very well, but I'm having some issues on a few client sites (with Pagination showing the wrong information and have pinpointed it down to the way we are loading the product collection on category pages.

In short, this module puts all relevant page information into a nice JavaScript object located at window.universal_variable.

When on the second(or later) category page, you will see something like this: (figure 1)

[image: figure 1]

This is where the 'non magic' happens:

```
<?php
class QuBit_UniversalVariable_Model_Observer
{
/**
 * Observes controller_action_layout_render_before
 * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
 */
public function processListingData(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    /** @var QuBit_UniversalVariable_Helper_Data $helper */
    $helper = Mage::helper('qubituv');
    $layout = Mage::app()->getLayout();
    /** @var Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List $block */
    $block = $layout->getBlock($helper->getCategoryProductListBlockName());
    if (!$block instanceof Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List) {
        $block = $layout->getBlock($helper->getSearchProductListBlockName());
        if (!$block instanceof Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List) {
            return;
        }
    }
    $uv = $helper->getUv();
    $listing = $uv->getListing();
    /** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection $collection */
    $collection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
    $listing['result_count'] = $collection->getSize();
    $listing['items'] = array();
    foreach($collection as $product) {
        $listing['items'][] = $uv->getProductData($product);
    }
    $toolbar = $block->getToolbarBlock();
    $listing['sort_by'] = $toolbar->getCurrentOrder() . '_' . $toolbar->getCurrentDirection();
    $listing['layout'] = $toolbar->getCurrentMode();
    $uv->setListing($listing);
 }
```

}

*Source: https://github.com/QubitProducts/UniversalVariable-Magento-Extension/blob/master/app/code/community/QuBit/UniversalVariable/Model/Observer.php*

and $uv->getProductData($product); looks like this:

```
/**
 * @param Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product
 * @return array
 */
public function getProductData(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product)
{
    $id = $product->getId();
    if (!$this->helper()->shouldUseRealProductId()) {
        $id = $product->getSku() ? $product->getSku() : md5($id);
    }
    $data = array(
        'id' => $id,
        'url' => $product->getProductUrl(),
        'name' => $product->getName(),
        'unit_price' => (float)$product->getPrice(),
        'unit_sale_price' => (float)$product->getFinalPrice(),
        'currency' => $this->_getCurrency(),
        'description' => strip_tags($product->getShortDescription()),
        'sku_code' => $product->getSku()
    );
    if ($this->helper()->shouldShowProductStockInfo()) {
        $data['stock'] = (int)Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product)->getQty();
    }
    $catIndex = $catNames = array();
    $limit = 2; $k = 0;
    foreach ($product->getCategoryIds() as $catId) {
        if (++$k > $limit) {
            break;
        }
        if (!isset($catIndex[$catId])) {
            $catIndex[$catId] = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId);
        }
        $catNames[] = $catIndex[$catId]->getName();
    }
    if (isset($catNames[0])) {
        $data['category'] = $catNames[0];
    }
    if (isset($catNames[1])) {
        $data['subcategory'] = $catNames[1];
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Source: https://github.com/QubitProducts/UniversalVariable-Magento-Extension/blob/master/app/code/community/QuBit/UniversalVariable/Model/Uv.php

Does anyone have any ideas on why using $block->getLoadedProductCollection() might be causing this? and whether we can add any filters to this? or another method of loading the products on a category page to populate our object.

Thanks!